# How to define function with property that is another function in React and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

To add a function with property in TypeScript you can use this code:

```js
// type alias for `verifyAge` function
// with function signature and a property with its type
type VerifyAgeFunc = {
  (age: number): boolean;
  usedBy: string;
};

// the function itself that
// satisfies the above type alias
let verifyAge = <VerifyAgeFunc>((age: number) => (age > 18 ? true : false));

// add a property called `usedBy`
verifyAge.usedBy = "Admin"; // allowed ✅.
```

Found in this article [How to add properties to function in TypeScript?](https://melvingeorge.me/blog/add-properties-to-functions-typescript) and this is the recommended way. The problem is that I need this in ReactNative and JSX.

I want to define the component CharText and inside define CharText.Animated component, similar to what you do with compound components (but I don't know any library that does this right now so I'm not able to check how they did it, and if they use TypeScript).

This is my attempt:

```js
interface CharTextFunc {
  (props: CharTextProps): ReactNode;
  Animated: (props: CharTextProps) => ReactNode;
}

const CharText = <CharTextFunc,>({ mapStyle, style, children, ...restProps }: CharTextProps) => (
  <View style={styles.container} {...restProps}>
    {[...children].map((chr, index) => (
      <Text key={`${chr}-${index}`} style={[styles.char, style, mapStyle && mapStyle(index, chr)]}>
        {chr}
      </Text>
    ))}
  </View>
);
```

the comma is needed to distinguish from JSX, but it doesn't work. Got a warning in both places where `CharTextFunc` is used that the variable is defined but not read.

I've tried a different approach with a higher-order component:

```js
interface CharTextFunc {
  (props: CharTextProps): ReactNode;
  Animated?: (props: CharTextProps) => ReactNode;
}

type TextComponent = typeof Animated.Text | typeof Text;

const makeCharText = (Text: TextComponent): CharTextFunc => {
  const ({ mapStyle, style, children, ...restProps }: CharTextProps) => (
    <View style={styles.container} {...restProps}>
      {[...children].map((chr, index) => (
        <Text key={`${chr}-${index}`} style={[styles.char, style, mapStyle && mapStyle(index, chr)]}>
          {chr}
        </Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

const CharText = makeCharText(Text);

CharText.Animated = makeCharText(Animated.Text);
```

But this doesn't allow me to call CharText.Animated because Animated is optional, and if I want to use Animated as mandatory I end up with the same problem where I need to use generic like syntax that doesn't work in JSX.

Comment: Have you considered just using normal functions and not having to deal with generics being confused for tags?

Comment: @kelsny thanks, I think this is what I will do. But still, I would like to know how to add properties to function in React. This may be a bug in TypeScript/JSX. If no one replies on how to do this, I will open an issue in the TypeScript repo on GitHub. Also, I think that this is not a generic only a similar looking construct. Because generics work fine like this in React (when you add a comma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one give proper answer so I reported it as a [bug to TypeScript project](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55874).

They suggested that a proper idiomatic way is to use `as T` syntax. Which in fact is the same type annotation syntax as `<T>`.

```js
interface CharTextFunc {
  (props: CharTextProps): ReactNode;
  Animated: (props: CharTextProps) => ReactNode;
}

const makeCharText = (Text: TextComponent) => {
  const ({ mapStyle, style, children, ...restProps }: CharTextProps) => (
    <View style={styles.container} {...restProps}>
      {[...children].map((chr, index) => (
        <Text key={`${chr}-${index}`} style={[styles.char, style, mapStyle && mapStyle(index, chr)]}>
          {chr}
        </Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

const CharText = makeCharText(Text) as CharTextFunc

CharText.Animated = makeCharText(Animated.Text);
```